How to copy char data to a smaller char already defined in memory?
Maybe this is an easy one but i could not find solution.
in function :
int function(char **data)
{
char data_new[542] = {.......};
memcpy(*data, data_new, sizeof(data_new));
return 1;
}

It does not work because *data is smaller size of data_new. How to properly increase the size of *data to be successful memcpy()? I don't want to just do:
*data = data_new;

I want to copy the data to this area of memory where this pointer points.
I tried:
*data = (char*)realloc(*data, sizeof(data_new) * 2);

Thanks in advance.

Is *data allocated (Which is it size)? or do you have to malloc yourself?

It is allocated. I tried: data = (char)malloc(sizeof(char) * data_size); but it didn't work.

Showing calling site might help.

Resizing the caller's buffer should not be this function's responsibility.

“it didn’t work” is not an adequate problem description. Using realloc is a correct way to reallocate dynamically allocated memory. To figure out why it did not work, you should edit the question to provide a [mre].

@pulpf If you do not know how to resolve the problem yourself then it obviously means that you are doing something wrong. For example you have an incorrect design of your program including used functions.


How to copy char data to a smaller char already defined in memory?

You realloc():
// Error checking omitted
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
// your original function with (almost) no changes
int function(char **data) {
    char data_new[542] = "bar";
    data_new[541] = 'Z';              // just to illustrate
    *data = realloc(*data, 542);      // realloc, would be better to receive the original size
                                      // and have a way to send back the new size
    memcpy(*data, data_new, sizeof(data_new));
    return 1;
}
 
int main(void) {
    char *foo = malloc(200);
    function(&foo);
    printf("%c%c%c ... %c\n", foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[541]);
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}

See https://ideone.com/v10p2S

Warning: no array in the above code is a string (except data_new right after initialization)

Thanks i already tried this but got: C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Are you sure you defined foo as a pointer (and allocated some memory to make foo point to)? Not a plain array of char?

You might like Microsoft's explanation of that error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/c0000005

This is how it worked:
int function(char **data)
{
   char data_new[542] = {.......};
   *data= (char*)realloc(*data, 560);
   SecureZeroMemory(*data, 560);
   memcpy(*data, data_new, 542);
   return 1;
}

Thanks.

This is very similar to what you said (in comments) you did. Maybe you also changed something in the function that calls this one? Something important and worthy of mention?

No other changes. Just the reallocated space has to be a bit more than what you have to copy.

BTW: your cast to realloc() call indicates a) failure to #include <stdlib.h> b) using a C++ compiler or c) abuse of code redundancy :-) Try #ifdef __cplusplus / #error bad compiler / #endif

"the reallocated space has to be a bit more than what you have to copy" ... again a problem only relevant to the function that calls this one. Glad you've got it sorted!
